# MySQL: subquery in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a problem. I want to use subquery `tm` in `LEFT JOIN .. ON`

```
SELECT t.*, 
    (SELECT `uid` FROM `truck_transport` tm WHERE tm.from = t.station ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as tm 
FROM `truck_trailer` t 
LEFT JOIN `truck_transport` tm2 ON (tm2.uid = tm) ...
```

If I use subquery in `FROM` result of rand is always the same.

Sorry for my language :/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT t.*, tm.uid
FROM `truck_trailer` t 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `uid` FROM `truck_transport` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as tm 
    ON (tm.uid = t.station)
```

Comment: Always return the same value :/

Comment: Can you please create an SQLFiddle here (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with both your tables and some sample data and expected results. How many records do you have in `truck_transport` table? Are there multiple records in `truck_trailer` table matching multiple records in `truck_transport`. Returning same result also depends on the data in `truck_trailer` table too

Answer (score 0):

mynawaz has written a correct query.

Your subquery will always return only one result because of `limit 1`. If you want only one result to come then use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. because left join table always returns matching rows and non matching with `NULL` of right side table.